# Android Saving Data to application

Tags: android

Is there some way in android to save objects to a place where they can be accessed by different activities of the same application? Without having to serialize or parcel the object?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 best ways for passing objects between activities is using a static field probably in a class that extends `Application`, or (probably preferably) use a service and have your activities that need to share objects bind to it.

Be careful about using static fields in `Activities` however, as they can be destroyed at any time and are thus not thread safe and potentially disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreferences` is the way to go. Put this in the activity

```
 public void saveSetting(String settingName, String value){
  SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  Editor ed = pref.edit();
  ed.putString(settingName, value);  
  ed.commit();  
 }
```

Comment: I would want to pass objects that I created myself. As far as I see SharedPreferences only work with buildin types.

Comment: Serialise it to string, perhaps using JSONObject.

Comment: Aliostad speaks truth.  Bite the bullet and serialize your objects.  One way or another, you'll have to do this to save your data.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference is only good for objects that SharedPreferences supports. For *any* long term storage of objects you will have to go down the serialized route of some sort. I am guessing you have read the [Data Storage page in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). From there I would recommend you reading about [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). If you don't want to deal with Java's serializble interface then I suggest you check out [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

XStream coupled with Internal Storage may offer the solution you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a point of permanence maintaining a global application state without using serialization, databases etc, use a Service or the Application class. General tips on this issue found at [android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences or create a Singleton class. I used singleton class to control the lifecycle of the attributes. If you want guaranteed persistance,store data in a sqllite db.

Using Singleton, you can store custom objects.

```
public class MySingleton {
private static final AlphResourceSet INSTANCE = new MySingleton ();
private MySingleton() {}
public static MySingleton getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
   // all your getters/setters for your variables
}
```